# Custom sorting using LINQ and Function

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of strings each of which are exactly 2 characters long. I wish to sort it. 
I begin by sorting the list by the first character of each string using

```
.OrderBy(e => e[0])
```

but my problem is when sorting the second character, something like:

```
.ThenBy(string1 => string1, string2 => string2 Compare(string1,string2)
```

I want to select two strings and pass them to the function I created called compare.

Can someone tell me how I would do this or if there is a better way of doing what I want? 
Please share.

```
public string sortT(string h)
{
    var sortedList = l
                    .OrderBy(e => e[0])
                    .ThenBy()
                    .ToList<string>();
    return sb.ToString();
}
private int Compare(string a, string b)
{
    List<char> value = new List<char>() {
        '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','J','Q', 'K', 'A' };           
    if (value.IndexOf(a[1]) > value.IndexOf(b[1]))
        return 1; 
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Why not `ThenBy(str => str[1])`?

Comment: because the ascii values of [J-A] are not the same as what i need. 'A' is considered the largest value for my problem but its ASCII value is 65 (less that J = 74). Hence the list<char> to specify the correct order.

Comment: An example would be useful as it's not crystal clear exactly what the issue is or what ordering you want.

Comment: you can define your own compare rule use `Queryable.ThenBy<TSource, TKey> Method (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>, IComparer<TKey>)` :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PaulZahra: The Compare function shows clearly what the ordering would be. The OP seems to have a character for a value of a suit of cards. They have a List defining the order that they want things. The compare function works, the OP is just asking how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your list as basis:

```
List<char> value = new List<char>() { '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','J','Q', 'K', 'A' };

var sortedList = l.OrderBy(str => str[0])
                  .ThenBy(str => value.IndexOf(str[1]))
                  .ToList<string>();
```

You could also implement a custom `IComparer<T>` like this:

```
public class TwoCharComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static readonly List<char> value = new List<char>() { '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' };

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null || x.Length < 2 || y.Length < 2) return 0; // ignore
        int comparison = x[0].CompareTo(y[0]);
        if (comparison != 0)
            return comparison;
        int ix1 = value.IndexOf(x[1]);
        int ix2 = value.IndexOf(y[1]);
        if(ix1 == ix2 && ix1 == -1)
            return x[1].CompareTo(y[1]);  
        else
            return ix1.CompareTo(ix2);
    }
}
```

Now you can pass that to `List.Sort` which does not need to create a new list:

```
var l = new List<string> { "C1", "B2", "A2", "B1", "A1", "C3", "C2" };
l.Sort(new TwoCharComparer()); // A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,C3
```

Comment: Great!Thanks man this works perfectly. But just out of curiosity, does linq allow for this? selecting two elements at a go? or is there no need to have that feature?

Comment: @TheJackal: what do you want to select? Note that i've edited my answer to provide a different approach.

Comment: many thanks for second approach as well, I know it'll be useful in the future.